# Function works on localhost but not on server

Tags: php

I made a function to get the main folder path in which website is stored. In localhost it works fine.

```
function get_path()
{

    $current=dirname(__FILE__) . '/';   
    $name=basename(__DIR__);
    $from=array($name);
    $to=array('');
    $result=str_replace($from,$to,$current);    

return trim($result, "/\\");
}
```

But in server it shows error while including files.

```
 include(): Failed opening 'home3/home/public_html/dev/ship\model\main.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php')
```

The file is there in that directory for sure. But its not working.

Comment: Why are you trimming the leading `/` from an absolute filepath?

Comment: its because to remove extra / from the folder name which i am removing

Comment: But that's precisely what is causing your problem, you should __not__ be trimming the leading `/`

Comment: My goal is to make function which can be used to include files from file already inside a folder. Suppose i have include folder and it has db.php file . i want to make a function to include that file from a file which is inside include/modules/class/config.php

Comment: Instead of `/` it is adviced to use the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: the '/' in pathnames works on windows as well as unix. Unless deploying on some platform that doesn't use a '/' as the pathname separator then always use '/'.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Peter. Ill keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
// Define directory separator
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

function get_path()
{

    $current = dirname(__FILE__) . DS;
    $name = basename(__DIR__);
    $from = array($name);
    $to = array('');
    $result = str_replace($from, $to, $current);

    return $result;
}
```

Or you could use:

```
// define directory separator
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

function get_path($withSlash = true)
{
    $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    if ($trailingSlash) {
        $path .= DS;
    }
    return $path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're stripping out the first slash (first character) - plus you're using \ instead of / in the path.

Answer (score 0):

For the creation of paths you should use the PHP-function realpath to manage the slashes: http://php.net/realpath